# OWASP suppression, ignore entire folder

Tags: gradle, owasp, owasp-dependency-check

I am using the owasp dependency tool with retirejs and I am trying to figure out how to exclude an entire folder in my build.  Right now I have it as so

```
dependencyCheck{
    outputDirectory = "${projectDir}/reports"
    suppressionFile = "${projectDir}/gradle/owasp_config/suppress.xml"
    analyzers {
        experimentalEnabled = true
        assemblyEnabled = false
        retirejs { 
            filterNonVulnerable = true
        }
    }
    scanSet = ['build/deploy/scripts']
}
```

but with in  the scanSet is a folder with yui in it which I want to completely ignore during scan.  I could suppress the individual cve's in the suppression file but there are over 300 of them so a global exclusion would be a much better solution.